# How to insert students records in SQLite3 db using ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I am new to ROR. I am using Rails-4 and Ruby 1.9.3. I want to insert all student records into database. Please help to write the actual format. I have table named "Student" with the following fields

```
1)FIRST NAME.
2)LAST NAME.
3)DATE OF BIRTH(format-dd-mm-yy,select from option).
4)EMAIL ID.
5)MOBILE NUMBER
6)GENDER.(select from radio button value)
7)ADDRESS 
8)CITY
9)PIN CODE
10)STATE
11)COUNTRY
12)HOBBIES (It takes from check box value)
13)QUALIFICATION.
  format:
   sl no   Examination  Board   Percentage   Year of Passing
     1     Class X      -         -           -
     2     Class XI     -         -           -       

14)COURSES APPLIED FOR(takes fron radio button select value)
```

I wanted to run command `rails g model Student FIRST NAME:string etc`. What is the proper command to insert all the fields in given format or any other easiest way, please share with me.
Also please share some code snippet for retrieving all the values to controller page, if my method is inside controller page after submit.

```
def create

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The rails generator command is really easy:

`$ rails g model Student first_name:string last_name:string date_of_birth:date email:string mobile_number:string gender:string address:string city:string pin_code:string state:string country:string courses_applied_for:string`

For the `qualitfication` and the `hobbies` you will have to add separate models:

`$ rails g model Qualitification examination:string board:string percentage:decimal year_of_passing:string student_id:integer:index`

`$ rails g Hobbie title:string student_id:integer:index`

The `student` model should look like this:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :hobbies
 has_many :qualifications

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :hobbies
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :qualifications
end
```

The `Hobbie` model:

```
class Hobbie < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :student
end
```

The `Qualification` model:

```
class Qualification < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :student
end
```

Next for the `students_controller`

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
 def new
  @student = Student.new
 end

 def create
  @student = Student.new(student_params)
  if @student.save
   redirect_to root_path
   else
   render :new
  end
 end

 private

  def student_params
   params.require(:student).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :date_of_birth, :email, :mobile_number, :gender, :address, :city, :pin_code, :state, :country, :courses_applied, hobbies_attributes: [:title], qualifications_attributes: [:examination, :board, :percentage, :year_passing])
  end
end
```

And finally the form should look something like the one below, I'm going to ignore the student fields, I will show you the hobbies and qualifications:

```
<%= form_for @student do |f| %>
.
.
.
 <%= f.fields_for :qualifications do |qf| %>
  <%= qf.text_field :examination %>
  <%= qf.text_field :board %>
  <%= qf.text_field :percentage %>
  <%= qf.text_field :year_of_passing %>
 <% end %>
 <%= f.fields_for :hobbies do |qf| %>
  <%= qf.text_field :title %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If you want to dinamycally add more `qualifications` or `hobbies` I recommend you check out the  [nested_form gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) from Ryan Bates, it will help you a lot.

Hope this helps!